# ¿como crear una funcion en SQL server para traducir fechas en 3 idiomas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

como puedo crear una funcion que reciba 2 parametros un datetime y otro el idioma.
que traduzca por ejemplo: domingo 12 agosto 2018 ingles thursday 12 agust 2018

Comment: Intentaste algo? asi como esta, la pregunta va a ser cerrada porque no demostras que intentaste algo.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. [edit] la pregunta agregando qué has intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de "SET LANGUAGE".

Dentro de tu función podrías tener una condición preguntando por tu segundo parámetro, te doy una pista.

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME;  
SET @Today = '12/5/2007';  

SET LANGUAGE Italian;  
SELECT DATENAME(month, @Today) AS 'Month Name';  

SET LANGUAGE us_english;  
SELECT DATENAME(month, @Today) AS 'Month Name' ;  
GO
```

Prueba y me cuentas.